# Cortana OAuth2 authentication - unable to delete it

Tags: oauth-2.0, cortana-skills-kit

[image: Cortana Auth option delete]

I configured the Auth provider in my Cortana skill and removed it. After removing it still appear in the cortana dashboard and doesn't allow me to either Edit or Add new OAuth provider.

Do I need to go to any other Vault and delete the configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: yes, i am still experiencing it